# Run-Length encoding gives the same number to all repeating values

Tags: python, compression, run-length-encoding

I am building a compressor for short strings mixing different compression algorithms and RLE is one of it and which is giving the problem.

The script I have now is the following, altough pretty incomplete at the moment:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

dictionary = {'hello':'\§', 'world':'\°', 'the': '\@', 'for': '\]'}
a_test_string = 'hello******** to the world****!'

def compress(string, dictionary):
    pattern = re.compile( '|'.join(dictionary.keys() )) 
    result = pattern.sub(lambda value: dictionary[value.group() ], string)

    '''
    Here I should also implement a snippet to check for characters beginning with "\" so that they won't get replaced and screw up the result.
    '''

    for character in string:
        occurrence = string.count(character*2)
        there_is_more_than_one_occurrence = occurrence > 1

        if there_is_more_than_one_occurrence:

                second_regex_pass_for_multiple_occurrences = re.sub('\*\*\*+', '/'+character+str(occurrence), result)
                result = second_regex_pass_for_multiple_occurrences

    print 'Original string:', string

    print 'Compressed string:', result

    print 'Original size:', len(string)

    print 'Compressed size:', len(result)


compress(a_test_string, dictionary)
```

When I run the function I get this:

```
Original string: hello******** to the world****!
Compressed string: \§/*6 to \@ \°/*6!
Original size: 31
Compressed size: 20
```

But I should be getting:

```
Original string: hello******** to the world****!
Compressed string: \§/*8 to \@ \°/*4!
Original size: 31
Compressed size: 20
```

What I'm doing wrong here that I get both *6* as the count of repeating chars?

Comment: Aside: your indentation looks weird, which is often a sign of mixed tabs and spaces.  Could you check to make sure you're using consistent indentation (one way is to run your script using `-tt`, e.g. `python -tt your_program_name.py`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try to understand exactly what you're doing, but a good debug method is to add some "print" statements inside your for loop or to use the python debugger and see what's actually happening. Try running some of these calls yourself and see what's being returned.

I think your main problem is that "string.count" returns the count for the entire string so when it checks for 2 `*`s the first time it sees all 12 (or technically all 6 patterns of `**`). When the for loop checks the next set of `*`s it is still checking the entire string. Hope this helps.